# How do a decode the `tweet.json` returned from a twitter API request?

Tags: php, json, twitter

How do a decode the `tweet.json` returned from a twitter API request?
My JSON output: [www.screensystem.nl/twitter.php](http://screensystem.com/php) 
**PHP:**

```
<?php

require "Twitteroauth/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$consumer_key = "";
$consumer_secret = "";
$access_token = "";
$access_token_secret = "";


$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
$content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");

$statuses = $connection->get("search/tweets", ["q" => "@TMobile_Webcare"], ["lang" => "NL"]);
//json_encode($statuses);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($statuses);
echo "</pre";

echo $statuses  [0]->text;


?>
```

**UPDATE 17/6**

I have tried the code below, but I get a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
$content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");

$statuses  = $connection->get("search/tweets", ["q" => "@TMobile_Webcare"], ["lang" => "NL"]);

// get your json as an associative array
$jsonArray = json_encode($statuses,true);

// loop through our json array
foreach($jsonArray as $key=>$data) {
            echo $tweet['created_at'];

    // if $data is an array, and you want to loop through it
    foreach($data as $dataKey=>$dataValue) {
        echo $tweet['text'];
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `json_encode()`. If you want to get them as an array instead of a stdObject use `true` as the 2nd argument.

```
// get your json as an associative array
$jsonArray = json_encode($statuses,true);

// loop through our json array
foreach($jsonArray as $key=>$data) {
    // do what you want to here

    // if $data is an array, and you want to loop through it
    foreach($data as $dataKey=>$dataValue) {
        // do something here if you needed to
    }
}
```

Comment: Thkns, and how can i make a foreach loop with te results?